# Phonegap Build creates wrong APK file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm creating an APK file using https://build.phonegap.com/. Once I install it on my phone and open it, I can't see my dummy app, instead it shows me this page: https://nodeca.github.io/pako/. Pako is not related to my project at all.

It makes no difference if I add my source code to Phonegap using github or .zip. My code works locally using Phonegap Desktop.

Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: Are you repackaging your app for Build? The folder structure for PG on the desktop is quite different to that for Build, no?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect you are correct. There is a difference.

Comment: @kvothe, please *add the following information to your* **post**. Is this your first App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Then respond here that you have put that information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem.

My first app.
Target: android

I created my dummy app with Phonegap Desktop app. I changed the html,js,css files and then I ziped the project directory and  build it in the cloud and it generates the apk. When I download it and install it on my phone (also other Phones) it just get the following screen (http://postimg.org/image/x01n44j4x/).

It works propertly with the Phonegap app or in the browser but not with the built apk.

EDIT: I solved the problem

What was wrong: zipping the whole project directory
How I solved: I just zipped the "www" folder and uploaded it to build the apks again => it worked :DD

EDIT 2:

also include the config.xml file, this is very important..otherwise you get later errors and things dont work like they should